# Mule 3 - how do I iterate over each header?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to find if any of the header value contains a certain value say  `Moscow`.
Note - I would NOT know the names upfront of headers so I cannot search by header name ( as an example ) :

```
message.inboundProperties.Accept
```

So I need a way to iterate over whatever are the incoming headers and then check their values .
I am struugling how to achieve this in Mule 3 using Dataweave 1 ?

Comment: What's the expected answer? True or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DataWeave 1.x (Mule 3.x) [inboundProperties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-selectors#inbound-properties-from-a-mule-message) is an [object](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-types#object) (a collection of key-values) that contains a key with the name of the property. You can use any technique that you would use to do the same search in any other object. For example using the `pluck` operator to get a list of values in the object, map the list to check if the element contains the desired value, then reduce the list of resulting booleans by using a logical or operation.

It could be similar to this:

```js
((inboundProperties pluck $) map ($ contains "Moscow")) reduce ((item, acc=false) -> acc or item)
```

I don't have access to test it at the moment but hopefully you get the idea.

Then I recommend that you implement it as a function for easier use so you can pass the value to search as a parameter.

DataWeave 2.x certainly has much better functions to implement this kind of expressions more easily.